# Which item type should I use for jenkins when I want to have work done on a particular slave agent?

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to jenkins and trying to get started for my team (previously working with Bamboo). I'm in an environment where I have 1 jenkins server and many slave agents. There is 1 specific agent where I want to do most of my work/build on because it's the agent that my team owns.

Initially, I thought freestyle project would suit me, but I can't see a way to restrict a particular build step to a specific slave agent. Would pipeline be the best fit for me in this case? Is there a way to specify a specific node in freestyle?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyzL1.png)

Answer (score 1):

In freestyle project, you can set `Restrict where this project can be run` in the `Configure` page to select where you can run your project.

[image]

Also [the NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) will help if you want to specify the node as an parameter for a project.

Comment: I just tried setting up jenkins on my personal machine and I don't see that item exposed between "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" and "Quiet period". Is it because I don't have slave nodes setup?

Comment: @firstblud, No, there is at least one node (`master` which is the Jenkins master) you can choose.